# IIS Rewrite to Block URL with Special Characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have the following url's using which my site is accessed:

```
http://www.itsmysitesitesite.com/showproduct.aspx?id=230
http://www.itsmysitesitesite.com/browseproduct.aspx?catid=100
```

I want to write a IIS Rewrite Rule that blocks a url if the ID= or catid= portion starts with minus (-)

Eg: block these urls

```
http://www.itsmysitesitesite.com/showproduct.aspx?id=-230
http://www.itsmysitesitesite.com/showproduct.aspx?id=-2%27
http://www.itsmysitesitesite.com/browseproduct.aspx?catid=-1
```

How do I write this rule? I am using IIS 8.0 on a Windows 2012 R2 machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following configuration

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <denyUrlSequences>
        <add sequence="id=-" />
      </denyUrlSequences>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Won't this specifically deny the url if it has a '-' anywhere in the url. I want to target only the portion after ID or CatID

Comment: this will deny the url if it has a  '-' but u can add "id=-" in denyurlsequences

Comment: Ok and for CatID I add another sequence like <add sequence="id=-" /><add sequence="catid=-" /> right?

Comment: yeah I am trying it as we chat..will update in a short while :)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. When I test it, my site triggers the error handler routine and throws an exception Unexpected error occurred!

Comment: Does the IIS Rewrite rule fire before the Page_Load event of a page?

Comment: Y dont u check on ur page load?

Comment: How? What do I write in the Load?

Comment: just check following two URLS<br/> http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/denyurlsequences

Comment: if convert.toint32(request.querystring("id")) <0  <br/>response.redirect("errorpage.aspx")<br/> end if

Comment: actually the answer is to include a filtering rule and specify to scanUrl and scanQAueryString. It's working now. Thanks for your help and the pointers.